# ElasticSearch - Restricting primary shards to specific nodes in cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, scalability, sharding

I have 5 node ES cluster, Is it possible to restrict primary shards to say first 3 nodes of the cluster or I can configure nodeA, nodeB and nodeC to hold the primary shards. Primary shards should not get rebalanced on other nodes say nodeD and NodeE.

Is there any such kind of configuration available in ES.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: We are using older version 2.4.4, and need to put a cluster in auto-scaling so problem arises when the cluster ramp-down the nodes. So I can keep first 3 nodes of cluster static  (no auto scaling) and other data nodes can be configured in auto scaling.

Answer (score 1):

you can use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/allocation-filtering.html to keep **shards** on specific nodes, that applies to primaries and replicas. but there's nothing to keep just primaries on specific nodes if you have replicas as well

also 2.4 is 6 years old, you really need to upgrade